# Cumulative sum, with lag, by group, on date-stamped observations

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, dplyr

I have this data set of batting data from the GameDay servers:

```
  eliasID teamID                     gameID gameDate h hr bb so rbi ab runs t d lob sb cs sf hbp

1  430203    kca 2010/04/01/arimlb-kcamlb-1 4/1/2010 1 2    0 0 0   0  0  0  0   0

2  459714    kca 2010/04/01/arimlb-kcamlb-1 4/1/2010 1  0  0  1   0  3    1 0 0   1  0  0  0   0

3  325392    kca 2010/04/01/arimlb-kcamlb-1 4/1/2010 0  0  1  0   0  1    0 0 0   0  0  0  0   0

4  429801    kca 2010/04/01/arimlb-kcamlb-1 4/1/2010 0  0  0  1   0  3    0 0 0   2  0  0  0   0

5  456714    kca 2010/04/01/arimlb-kcamlb-1 4/1/2010 0  0  1  0   0  4    0 0 0   2  0  0  0   0

6  150449    kca 2010/04/01/arimlb-kcamlb-1 4/1/2010 0  0  0  1   1  4    0 0 0   2  0  0  0   0

     ba ID gameDateFormat year Year
1 0.345  1     2010-04-01 2010   NA
2 0.250  2     2010-04-01 2010   NA
3 0.319  3     2010-04-01 2010   NA
4 0.327  4     2010-04-01 2010   NA
5 0.333  5     2010-04-01 2010   NA
6 0.217  6     2010-04-01 2010   NA
```

My issue is that I'd like to build a running total of at bats (ab) for each game, but total only those at bats from games with gameDate lower than the row's gameDate, and with games in the same gameYear.

I've look at the for loop and dplyr has been suggested, but these all want to sum all the ab column for one player, when I need an ongoing sum added to each game to show the player's ab total for the year so far at that game.

I'm attempting to build the equivalent of the kind of statistics you see on baseball-ref.com.

In English, I'm looking for:

For each EliasID, gameID in Batting:
 sum(ab) for the EliasID where the gameDate < this row's gameDate and the gameYear = this row's gameYear

What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please see [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2573061).  As written, your problem is not very clear or reproducible.

Comment: I feel like this question was an honest effort by a new user and should not be instantly downvoted.

Comment: It is sum(ab) or sum(ba)?

Comment: @Robert presumably `ab` is "at bats", and `ba` is "batting average," which doesn't really make sense to sum

Comment: I was not able to make a reproducible example from the web page you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to R programming.  Because you did not provide complete sample data (i.e. `dput()` rather than just a `print()`, this answer makes a couple assumptions:

- your `data.frame` is called `df`.  You can replace this name with the actual name.
- your `gameDate` is an actual date vector, not just a string vector.  If it is a string, change it to a date with `df$gameDate <- as.Date(df$gameDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")`

It appears that what you want is a "cumulative sum with lag, by group."  (I recommend that you make this your title to make it clear that this is what you want.) Let's look at both of those parts.

### Cumulative sum, with lag

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649206/cumulative-sum-with-lag), an easy way to introduce a lag of 1 into `cumsum()` is to replace the vector `x1, x2, ... xn` with `0, x1, x2, ... xn-1`.  Thus:

```
cumsumLag1 <- function(x){
  cumsum(c(0, head(x, n = -1))) # see ?cumsum and ?head, particularly the note on negative n
}
# test it out on first 5 counting numbers
cumsumLag1(1:5) # returns: 0  1  3  6 10
```

Your dataset should be in the right chronological order for the cumulative function.  So you could do something with `?order` like:

```
df <- df[order(df$gameDate)]
```

but we will use `arrange()` in `dplyr` (see below) to keep things simple.

### By group

There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group) to do sum (and similar functions) by group.  Perhaps the simplest syntax is `%>% group_by(thing)` in `dplyr`.  You want to group by year, and perhaps other variables (maybe teamId or playerId).  *One really unclear part of your question is what you're trying to group by, so please just focus on the concept here.*  The first challenge is that you don't have a `year` variable, and there are lots of ways to do this.  Let's just do something like this:

```
df$gameYear <- as.POSIXlt(df$gameDate)$year + 1900 # see ?POSIXlt for more details
```

### Putting it together

Using the chain operator `%>%`, we just sequence what we've already reviewed.

```
library(dplyr)

cumsumLag1 <- function(x) cumsum(c(0, head(x, n = -1))) 

df %>%
    mutate(gameYear = as.POSIXlt(gameDate)$year + 1900) %>%
    arrange(gameDate) %>%
    group_by(gameYear) %>%
    mutate(priorAtBats = cumsumLag1(ab))
```

Comment: Thanks so much C8H10N402! This was very helpful. It does look like I have some date clean up to do, along with using your ideas for putting together the at-bats.

Comment: Yes, I was being confusing with my terminology. I'm trying out dput() and so far I don't get it but I'll look again.

Comment: Thanks to you all, I have a brilliant set of data that uses this function:

Comment: @Marianne glad to help, if this answered your question then please feel free to accept it (click the check mark)